# A small puzzle. Why does this code work the way it does?

Tags: c++

This was given to me by a friend of mine, it prints out 0 through 9. We have been quite puzzled over this. Does anyone know why this works?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void x(int a)
{
    *(&a-1) += a;
}

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        x(8);
        i = 0;
        cout << i << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: CodeGolf.SE is a place [to post programming contests with well defined winning conditions](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/faq#questions). This would, perhaps have been better on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @dmckee I would have thought that "Programming puzzles" in the title would reference stuff like this. Sorry :)

Comment: Imho, this clearly belongs here, not stackoverflow, the closure reflects badly on the moderator.

Comment: `void(int a)` is never printed.  That function is just garbage.  What is actually being printed is variable `i`: `cout << i << endl;`  `i` is started at `0`: `int i = 0;`, then is incremented by `1`: `++i;`, as long as it is less than `10`.  The call `x(8)` does nothing and is unnecessary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, the line `*(&a-1) += a;` is undefined behavior, so this could do anything depending on compiler version, flags used, alignment of the stars, etc.

That said, the reason why it works in your case is probably because `&a-1` happens to point to the return address of `x`, and incrementing it by `8` causes the `i = 0;` to be skipped.

Comment: oh my god... that's nasty.

Comment: in other words a buffer overflow without the buffer (or a 1 element buffer)

Answer (score 4):

The reason this works is because your compiler passes the `a` parameter on the stack. Before the parameter, the code pushes the return address of the method onto the stack:

```
004A0008 | 00000008 ; a parameter
004A0004 | 00401200 ; return addr
004A0000 | ...
```

The `&a` part of the expression points to the *address* of the parameter on the stack, in this case I've used `004A0008`. The `a-1` then subtracts `sizeof(int)` from that address, giving you `004A0004`. The `*` dereferences that address, so its value can be edited. This means that when you add 8 to the value at `004A0004`, it alters the return address. When the method returns, it ends up 8 bytes ahead of where it should have been, skipping the `i=0`.